# How to utilize web service client generated from WSDL?

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, axis

I'm trying to write a simple web service client to interact with my simple web service which only returns a user id that's passed in.  So I created a web service client in eclipse and generated a few files for me; wsCall, wsCallBindingStub, wsCallProxy, wsCallService, wsCallServiceLocator.  The stub is the conly class I found that has my web service methods in it, because my ws is simple at this stage?

So I want to invoke the call, what do I need to make the call?

I've seen all the examples online have the try-catch for a remote exception or Axis fault, then the classes are instantiated (including a response class, to deserialize?) and make the ws call via the stub class.  Is that all I need to call for my case?

```
wsCallBindingStub stub = new wsCallBindingStub();
String retString = stub.sayHi(1); // 1: my user id
return retString;
```

Thank you!

Comment: I could help you if you were using JAX-WS, but i'm afraid i have no experience with Axis. It looks a lot more complex than JAX-WS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I figured it out, I was getting an error because my wsdl uses the hostname and I needed to specify the ip.. as for the code needed it was pretty much identicle;

```
wsCall ws = new wsCallServiceLocator().getWsCallPort();
result = ws.sayHi(x);
```